# Saving/transferring Input Values Between Two Methods in c#

Tags: c#, menu, console-application

I'm a beginning programmer creating a console application based menu in c# and am trying to figure out how to store an integer from input from one method/menu and transfer it to another menu. Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
public void SelectCustomer()
{

    //Prompts the user for the customer’s ID
    //If the customer does not exist then display an error
    //If the customer does exist then display the Customer menu

    int input;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your customer ID:");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (input)
    {
        case (1 - 5):
            CustomerMenu();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid ID. Please enter a valid ID:");
            break;
    }
    int[] CustomeridArray = { input, input, input, input, input };
}

public void CustomerMenu()
{
    //Display customer name, ID, and current order price
    //Display a menu with the following options:

    //1)Display current order
    //2)Add a product to the order
    //3)Remove a product from the order
    //4)Finalize the order
    //5)Return to Manager Customers menu

    int[] CustomerIDarray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Console.WriteLine("1) Display current order");
    Console.WriteLine("2) Add product to order");
    Console.WriteLine("3) Remove product from order");
    Console.WriteLine("4) Finalize order");
    Console.WriteLine("5) Return to Manage Customers Menu");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

How would I best go about storing the user input from the SelectCustomer menu and then referencing it in the CustomerMenu? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options, but I think the best would be to return the value from the first method and pass it as an argument to the second method:

```
public int32[] SelectCustomer() 
{ 
    // all your code
    return CustomeridArray;
}

public void CustomerMenu(int[] customerIDs) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: They're in the same class. Thanks very much! That's what I was looking for.